# How do we configure prometheus server to scrape metrics from a pod with Istio sidecar proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio-sidecar, istio-prometheus

A service pod is running with Istio sidecar container and is MTLS enabled. How do we define a service monitor to scrape metrics from this service ? Do we need to update the Prometheus server for the same ?

Comment: In order to support prometheus scraping, Istio versions 1.6 and above by default automatically inject annotations into pods with sidecar proxies.

Comment: Istio exposes Prometheus-format metrics automatically; you do not have to install it separately. You can run the following checks to verify that the Istio Proxy has been injected as a sidecar and that both Istiod, the control plane of Istio, and Istio Proxy are emitting metrics on the expected endpoints.



Refer to this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/exporters/istio#prerequisites) for more information

Comment: If automatic injection is disabled or you prefer manual configuration then you need to update the prometheus server configuration file to include a scrape target for the istio sidecar.make sure prometheus is able to find the target pods; this can be done by using the prometheus.yml file's static configuration or K8s service discovery.

Comment: Because of security considerations, it is not advised to expose metrics in plain text for production. Instead, secure scraping mechanisms such TLS authentication should be used.

Refer to this [doc](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/prometheus/) for more information

Comment: @ Nipunkumar Let me know whether the shared info was helpful. If the comments  was helpful